# Reactivity in Vue3 Composition API

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to get a Vue 3 component to react to changes in an underlying Typescript object. There is a plain (non-reactive) `Timer` object that updates its own public `percentRemaining` property from 100 to 0 via a recurring setTimeout object.

The timer counts down, and I can spit out its new value if I create a local interval function to spit out the value. But in the console I only get the "Timer remain" messages and never the "Watch remain" messages. I'm also showing the `percentRemaining` value in the component template, but it just remains 100.

The console shows something like:

```
Timer remain: 98.95958383353342
Timer remain: 97.93917567026811
Timer remain: 96.9187675070028
Timer remain: 95.87835134053621
Timer remain: 94.83793517406963
Timer remain: 93.81752701080433
Timer remain: 92.77711084433774
```

I have tried different flavors of `ref`, `toRef`, `toRefs` with the same results. I have tried wrapping the `percentRemaining` in a `computed(() => timer.percentRemaining)` - it also just returns the 100 without ever updating.

I can successfully get a local-to-the-component plain object to update with a similar `reactive` call and a local `setInterval`), and watching its counter works just fine.

I'm not sure whether this is due to the fact that I'm doing the external `setTimeout`, or just misunderstanding something fundamental about the Composition API.

```
import { defineComponent, reactive, watch } from 'vue';
import { Timer } from '@/app/timers/timer';

const TimerComponent = defineComponent({

    props: {
        timer: {
            type: Timer,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup(props) {

        const timer = reactive(props.timer);
        // const { timer } = reactive(props);
        // const { timer } = toRefs(props);

        const intervalTimer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(`Timer remain: ${timer.percentRemaining}`)
        }, 50);

        watch(() => timer.percentRemaining, (newValue) => {

            console.log(`Watch remain: ${newValue}`);

        });

        return {

            timer,
            intervalTimer

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: but you're not mutating the reactive state that will triggers the watcher

Comment: The object is updating itself on a timer. I am trying to port over some code that was running in a purely Typescript environment (without VueJS), and my hope was that there is a way to simply add reactive wrappers around my plain objects. I have had some success with moving the objects to either a Vuex store or just a `ref`-fed state object, and they are updating without the change having been initiated by a Component, but this one is elduing me. I'm still in my pre-Aha! lightbulb moment phase on tackling the Composition API, though.

Comment: `timer.percentRemaining` should be updated inside the timercomponent or from the parent?

Comment: I don't want the components to be in charge of updating the object, but I think the light is starting to dawn slightly. The other cases where something works - it's not coming from a component, but it *is* still working with the state/store object and passing "through" the reactive object reference to it. It seems like I can't get away with the logic being purely internal to the object. I was thinking that the `reactive` reference would still "know" that the value had changed, but that would rely on either polling it or something similar. You at least have me thinking - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. first, you use the same name **`timer`** in props and setup output, it may be a mistake.
2. what you want is: let vue know your direct operation on your own plain object.

   I dont think it possible
3. reactivity api is an independent module in vue, you can just use them as a reactive-functional package. all you need to do is replace your own timer obj with `reactive(your timer obj)` when you define them, and widthout any side effect